# GLM for comparing multiple series of values

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, biostatistics, underdispersion

First I want to say that I'm a beginner at statistics so sorry if my question contains errors.

I have analysed zebra finch song to find the time between the onset of notes in their song. For each bird the data will be a series of values that I want to compare for similarity. A simplified dataset for only two birds looks like this: [image] Each column is a different bird and each row is a different value.
My supervisor suggested using a GLM to compare the two series of data with each other. I am trying to make a good model but don't really know what error distribution to use. The one that seems to work the best is a gamma distribution, the model looks like this:

```r
Model <- glm(IOIfather ~ IOIson, family = Gamma(link="inverse"),
                     data = test.statistics2)
```

(IOIfather is the first column and IOIson is the second column.)

The data summary of this model looks like this:

[image]

I'm concerned about the fact that there seems to be under-dispersion and that the model only explains 49% of the data. Am I using the right model here or is It better to use another one? I've tried doing a Poisson distribution but that doesn't work since I have non-integer values.

EDIT: I'll add some more background, sorry I realise the question was a bit vague without more context.

The goal of my research is to see if young zebra finch males copy the rhythm of their father's song.
Therefore, I have analysed recordings for 10 father birds and their sons. For each bird I have analysed 10 songs. What the analysis contains is that I have measured the time between the onset of notes to get an idea of rhythm, each time difference between notes is an IOI value and eventually my dataset will have a series of IOI values per song. I want to compare these values of a father and a son to see if they are significantly similar or not.

EDIT2: have added a picture of the subset of the data.

[image]

Comment: What are your goals here?  What is it you want to learn from these data?  It isn't clear to me that any model makes sense.  Do you have some hypothesis you want to test? What?  What does it mean to "compare for similarity"?  Do you want to cluster the data?  How many birds do you have?

Comment: Poisson is only for count data.  I don’t understand the rationale for running a regression model on a single bird—I would think an average of all birds, or bird categories, would be more useful.  In that sense, I don’t understand the motivation for your model.  As for distributions, if you haven’t already, I would: a) see what distributions have been used in similar research; b) create a histogram of your data to see what distributions look like a best fit; c) consider transformations to see if they will fit into a Gaussian distribution so you can use a standard linear model.

Comment: @jeramytownsley sorry I realised my question was a bit vague so I have added some background that hopefully better conveys what I'm trying to accomplish. Your suggestions are great and I will use that approach, thank you!

Comment: @gung-ReinstateMonica I have added some background that will hopefully make it clear what I'm doing, sorry for my vagueness and thank you for trying to help!

Comment: Hmmm, I suspect this is a trickier analysis than you might suspect.  Can you post your dataset?

Comment: @gung-ReinstateMonica yes, I don't think I can post the whole excel file here so have added a picture of a subset of the data, if there is a better way please let me know. In this case, the songID starting with 18 is the father and the song starting with 12 is the son. Some more songs have to be added but it's mostly complete for this particular father-son pair. As you can see there are some missing values. This is because the notes had to be in the same 'place' in both songs, I will not use these missing values in my analysis since obviously there isn't anything to compare.

Comment: No one can work w/ a picture. Please copy & paste the data into the body of the question, or link to the dataset via something like google drive or dropbox.

Comment: @gung-ReinstateMonica https://drive.google.com/file/d/11qLz5X6INEL0qvuPloVcYN-ABttsQ8Zk/view?usp=sharing